# In Excel: with an array, how to pull duplicate data?

Tags: arrays, excel, offset

Current array:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$1:$C$2000,MATCH(1,(Data!$A$1:$A$2000='8157'!$C3)*(Data!$B$1:$B$2000='8157'!F$2),0),3),"")}
```

However this pulls only Kasper, John in every cell.  I've tried OFFSET in the second cell, but no luck.  Any ideas?  THANK YOU!

Data sheet:

```
LOCATION    JOBTITLE                        NAME
67          Assistant Manager Merchandise   Kasper,John
67          Assistant Manager Merchandise   Montresor,Britney
67          Assistant Manager Operations    Eldred,Joshua O.
```

Actual sheet:
Titles across the top and down the left side.  Data pulled from the data sheet using the array above. (Note Kasper, John is duplicated rather than pulling Montresor, Britney

```
Store # SVG General Manager Assistant Manager Merchandise   Assistant Manager Merchandise
67     5    Scudder,Debra        Kasper,John                    Kasper,John
168    4    Major,Stacey         Papp,Michael                   Papp,Michael
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have excel 2010 or later use this non CSE formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$1:$C$2000,AGGREGATE(15,6,Rows($1:$2000)/((Data!$A$1:$A$2000='8157'!$C3)*(Data!$B$1:$B$2000='8157'!F$2)),countif($F$2:F$2)),3),"")
```

If you have 2007 or earlier than use this CSE array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$1:$C$2000,SMALL(IF(((Data!$A$1:$A$2000='8157'!$C3)*(Data!$B$1:$B$2000='8157'!F$2)),Rows($1:$2000)),countif($F$2:F$2)),3),"")
```

This needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.